# Samsung Printer in CUPS rastertospl failed

Tags: cups

I've installed an Rasperry Pi with a standard Rasbian image. Now I want to use my printer with cups (Samsung CLX-3185 - connected via USB). I've installed the drivers from the Samsung webpage and the pi noticed the printer. But I can't print anything:

```
stopped  "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl failed"
```

Log file:

```
 d [03/Aug/2014:19:50:11 +0000] cupsdFinishProcess(pid=11326, name=0xbee803e4, namelen=1024, job_id=0xbee803e0(4)) = "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl"
 D [03/Aug/2014:19:50:11 +0000] PID 11326 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl) stopped with status 1.
 d [03/Aug/2014:19:50:11 +0000] select_timeout(-1): 30 seconds to write dirty config/state files
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: Have a similar problem...check: http://www.serveradminblog.com/2014/08/samsung-printer-on-linux-rastertosplc-no-such-file-or-directory/ Hope it works for U, too.

Comment: Sry, this does not fix the problem, because the tool does not work on a ARM CPU

Answer (score 3):

The `rastertospl` filter used for Samsung’s driver does appearently not work for armhf architectures (like Raspbian uses). However, you may have success with the splix-drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-splix
```

Splix also worked with the unlisted ML-1915 printer I had:
http://openprinting.org/driver/splix/

Comment: I can confirm the **printer-driver-splix** works with my MF-2165W (MF-2160 series)
Which is also a printer needing the rastertospl filter. Thanks

Comment: Can confirm that it worked for ML-1660, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do have a Samsung ML2160 plugged into an old arm-based NAS for which I can't find a working driver as Anders Johansonn.

Instead I setup a Generic PostScript Printer on the NAS with CUPS and share it over the network. Thus I can print from local computers on the network given that the driver is installed on them.

The drawback is that I can't print directly from the NAS but this is fine for me.